# What Pokemon in X & Y have access to Signature moves?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Kinda curious about this.  I know Greninja gets Mat Block and Water Shuriken (signature moves).

What Pokemon in X&Y have access to signature moves, and what are the moves?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The three starters each have their own signature moves:

- Chesnaught - [Spiky Shield](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/spikyshield.shtml)
- Delphox - [Mystical Fire](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/mysticalfire.shtml)
- Greninja - [Mat Block](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/matblock.shtml), [Water Shuriken](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/watershuriken.shtml)

As well as other assorted Pokemon:

- Vivillon - [Powder](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/powder.shtml)
- Litleo/Pyroar - [Noble Roar](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/nobleroar.shtml)
- Pancham/Pangoro - [Parting Shot](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/partingshot.shtml)
- Aegislash - [King's Shield](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/king%27sshield.shtml)
- Inkay/Malamar - [Topsy-Turvy](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/topsy-turvy.shtml)
- Helioptile/Heliolisk - [Electrify](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/electrify.shtml)
- Hawlucha - [Flying Press](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/flyingpress.shtml)
- Klefki - [Fairy Lock](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/fairylock.shtml), [Crafty Shield](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/craftyshield.shtml)
- Phantump/Trevenant - [Forest's Curse](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/forest%27scurse.shtml)
- Pumpkaboo/Gourgeist- [Trick-or-Treat](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/trick-or-treat.shtml)
- Aromatisse - [Aromatic Mist](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/aromaticmist.shtml)

And the Legendaries have their own signature moves:

- Xerneas - [Geomancy](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/geomancy.shtml)
- Yveltal - [Oblivion Wing](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/oblivionwing.shtml)
- Zygarde - [Land's Wrath](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/land%27swrath.shtml)

Comment: Note that this list can change as we discover some of these signature moves might be Egg Moves for other Pokemon.